# Download location for all (or at least the most common) W3C default Schemas and DTDs

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I'm writing an XML parsing tool, and I would like to cache all the most common XSDs and DTDs from W3C (with [XmlResolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlresolver?view=netframework-4.8)), and after some googling, I didn't manage to get them all. I would like to know if there's a place where I could download all default XML Schema Definitions and DTDs from W3C, or at least the most common standard ones.

These are the ones I got so far:

- [xml.xsd](https://www.w3.org/2009/01/xml.xsd)
- [XMLSchema.xsd](https://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd)
- [XmlSchema.dtd](https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd)
- [datatypes.dtd](https://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd)

What am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas

Comment: This is a great repo, @lexicore . Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lexicore referred you to github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas - that looks like a good resource, and I hadn't come across it before.

It took me a lot of work to get a reasonably full list for use in Saxon, and I think it's now moderately complete, but there are still occasional surprises. Here's the current list from Saxon 9.9 :

```
register("-//W3C//ENTITIES Latin 1 for XHTML//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent",
        "w3c/xhtml-lat1.ent");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES Symbols for XHTML//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-symbol.ent",
        "w3c/xhtml-symbol.ent");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES Special for XHTML//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-special.ent",
        "w3c/xhtml-special.ent");

register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd",
        "w3c/xhtml10/xhtml1-transitional.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd",
        "w3c/xhtml10/xhtml1-strict.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd",
        "w3c/xhtml10/xhtml1-frameset.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic10.dtd",
        "w3c/xhtml10/xhtml-basic10.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml11.dtd",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml11.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.1//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-basic11.dtd",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-basic11.dtd");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Access Element 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-access-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-access-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Access Attribute Qnames 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-access-qname-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-access-qname-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Java Applets 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-applet-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-applet-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Base Architecture 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-arch-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-arch-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Common Attributes 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-attribs-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-attribs-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Base Element 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-base-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-base-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Basic Forms 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-basic-form-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-basic-form-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Basic Tables 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-basic-table-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-basic-table-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Basic 1.0 Document Model 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-basic10-model-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-basic10-model-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Basic 1.1 Document Model 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-basic11-model-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-basic11-model-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML BDO Element 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-bdo-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-bdo-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML BIDI Override Element 1.0//EN", //should be "BDO Element 1.0" not "BIDI Override Element 1.0"
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-bdo-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-bdo-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Block Phrasal 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-blkphras-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-blkphras-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Block Presentation 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-blkpres-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-blkpres-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Block Structural 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-blkstruct-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-blkstruct-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Character Entities 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-charent-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-charent-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Client-side Image Maps 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-csismap-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-csismap-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Datatypes 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-datatypes-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-datatypes-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Editing Markup 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-edit-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-edit-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Editing Elements 1.0//EN",   // should be "Editing Markup" not "Editing Elements", but allow both
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-edit-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-edit-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Intrinsic Events 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-events-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-events-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Forms 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-form-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-form-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Frames 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-frames-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-frames-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Modular Framework 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-framework-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-framework-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML HyperAttributes 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-hyperAttributes-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-hyperAttributes-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Hypertext 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-hypertext-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-hypertext-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Frame Element 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-iframe-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-iframe-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Images 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-image-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-image-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Phrasal 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlphras-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inlphras-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Presentation 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlpres-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inlpres-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Structural 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlstruct-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inlstruct-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Inline Style 1.0//EN",  // should be "ELEMENTS" not "ENTITIES", but allow either
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Style 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inputmode 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inputmode-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inputmode-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Legacy Markup 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-legacy-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-legacy-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Legacy Redeclarations 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-legacy-redecl-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-legacy-redecl-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Link Element 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-link-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-link-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Lists 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-list-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-list-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Metainformation 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-meta-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-meta-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Metainformation 2.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-meta-2.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-meta-2.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML MetaAttributes 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-metaAttributes-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-metaAttributes-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Name Identifier 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-nameident-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-nameident-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//NOTATIONS XHTML Notations 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-notations-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-notations-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Embedded Object 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-object-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-object-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Param Element 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-param-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-param-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Presentation 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-pres-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-pres-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML-Print 1.0 Document Model 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-print10-model-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-print10-model-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Qualified Names 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-qname-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-qname-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML+RDFa Document Model 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-model-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-rdfa-model-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML RDFa Attribute Qnames 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-qname-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-rdfa-qname-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Role Attribute 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-role-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-role-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Role Attribute Qnames 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-role-qname-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-role-qname-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Ruby 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/ruby/xhtml-ruby-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-ruby-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Scripting 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-script-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-script-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Server-side Image Maps 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-ssismap-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-ssismap-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Document Structure 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-struct-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-struct-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML Style Sheets 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-style-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-style-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Style Sheets 1.0//EN",  // should be "DTD XHTML" not "ELEMENTS XHTML"
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-style-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-style-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Tables 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-table-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-table-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Target 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-target-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-target-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Text 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-text-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-text-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML 1.1 Document Model 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml11-model-1.mod",
        "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml11-model-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//MathML 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml1/mathml.dtd",
        "w3c/mathml/mathml1/mathml.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD MathML 2.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/mathml2.dtd",
        "w3c/mathml/mathml2/mathml2.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD MathML 3.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml3/mathml3.dtd",
        "w3c/mathml/mathml3/mathml3.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd",
        "w3c/svg10/svg10.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd",
        "w3c/svg11/svg11.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1 Tiny//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-tiny.dtd",
        "w3c/svg11/svg11-tiny.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1 Basic//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-basic.dtd",
        "w3c/svg11/svg11-basic.dtd");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Document Model//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-model.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg11-model.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Attribute Collection//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-attribs.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg11-attribs.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Modular Framework//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-framework.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-framework.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Datatypes//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-datatypes.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-datatypes.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Qualified Name//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-qname.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-qname.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Core Attribute//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-core-attrib.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-core-attrib.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Container Attribute//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-container-attrib.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-container-attrib.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Viewport Attribute//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-viewport-attrib.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-viewport-attrib.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Paint Attribute//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-paint-attrib.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-paint-attrib.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Paint Opacity Attribute//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-opacity-attrib.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-opacity-attrib.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Graphics Attribute//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-graphics-attrib.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-graphics-attrib.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Document Events Attribute//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-docevents-attrib.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-docevents-attrib.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Graphical Element Events Attribute//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-graphevents-attrib.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-graphevents-attrib.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Animation Events Attribute//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-animevents-attrib.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-animevents-attrib.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 XLink Attribute//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-xlink-attrib.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-xlink-attrib.mod");

register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 External Resources Attribute//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-extresources-attrib.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-extresources-attrib.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Structure//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-structure.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-structure.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Conditional Processing//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-conditional.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-conditional.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Image//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-image.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-image.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Style//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-style.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-style.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Shape//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-shape.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-shape.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Text//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-text.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-text.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Marker//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-marker.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-marker.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Color Profile//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-profile.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-profile.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Gradient//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-gradient.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-gradient.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Pattern//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-pattern.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-pattern.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Clip//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-clip.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-clip.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Mask//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-mask.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-mask.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Filter//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-filter.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-filter.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Cursor//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-cursor.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-cursor.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Hyperlinking//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-hyperlink.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-hyperlink.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 View//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-view.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-view.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Scripting//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-script.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-script.mod");


register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Animation//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-animation.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-animation.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Font//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-font.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-font.mod");

register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Extensibility//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-extensibility.mod",
        "w3c/svg11/svg-extensibility.mod");

register("-//XML-DEV//ENTITIES RDDL Document Model 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.rddl.org/xhtml-rddl-model-1.mod",
        "w3c/rddl/xhtml-rddl-model-1.mod");

register("-//XML-DEV//DTD XHTML RDDL 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.rddl.org/rddl-xhtml.dtd",
        "w3c/rddl/rddl-xhtml.dtd");

register("-//XML-DEV//ENTITIES RDDL QName Module 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.rddl.org/rddl-qname-1.mod",
        "w3c/rddl/rddl-qname-1.mod");

register("-//XML-DEV//ENTITIES RDDL Resource Module 1.0//EN",
        "http://www.rddl.org/rddl-resource-1.mod",
        "w3c/rddl/rddl-resource-1.mod");

register("-//XML-DEV//ELEMENTS RDDL Resource 1.0//EN",
         "http://www.rddl.org/rddl-resource-1.mod",
         "w3c/rddl/rddl-resource-1.mod");

register("-//XML-DEV//ENTITIES XLink Module 1.0//EN",
         "http://www.rddl.org/rddl-resource-1.mod",
         "w3c/rddl/xlink-module-1.mod");

register("-//W3C//DTD Specification V2.10//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/2002/xmlspec/dtd/2.10/xmlspec.dtd",
        "w3c/xmlspec/xmlspec.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD XMLSCHEMA 200102//EN",
        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd",
        "w3c/xmlschema10/XMLSchema.dtd");

register("datatypes",
        "http://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd",
        "w3c/xmlschema10/datatypes.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD XSD 1.1//EN",
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/XMLSchema.dtd",
         "w3c/xmlschema11/XMLSchema.dtd");

register("-//W3C//DTD XSD 1.1 Datatypes//EN",
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/datatypes.dtd",
         "w3c/xmlschema11/datatypes.dtd");

<!-- The last few are specific to XSLT/XQuery -->

register("xpath-functions",
        "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions.xsd",
        "xpath-functions.xsd");

register("json",
         "http://www.w3.org/2005/json.xsd",
         "xpath-functions.xsd");

register("analyze-string",
         "http://www.w3.org/2005/analyze-string.xsd",
         "xpath-functions.xsd");

register("xml-to-json",
        "xml-to-json.xsl",
        "xml-to-json.xsl");

register("xml-to-json-indent",
        "xml-to-json-indent.xsl",
        "xml-to-json-indent.xsl");
```

The arguments are first, the public ID if applicable, secondly, the W3C URI location, and third, the location in the data directory of the Saxon JAR file - you can download the Saxon source from SourceForge. Some of these files have more than one URI or more than one public ID: this is because W3C has published them or referenced them using multiple IDs.